# How to embed a wordpress page inside a nextjs page

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, next.js, divi

I have a Nextjs project where I want to show a Wordpress page on some of the pages. So for example on this route `products/[id]` I want to show a wordpress page that contains info related to that product below the main info. This is needed because for some of the designs we are using Divi.

At the moment the only solution I came up with was using and iframe to show the page (it works), but it feels a bit hacky and it's probably not the best solution. Is there a better way to do it? Thanks.

Comment: You can use [`rewrites`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites#rewriting-to-an-external-url) in `next.config.js`, or rewrite directly in Next.js [middleware](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/middleware).

Comment: I don't want to redirect to a different page, I want to show the page inside my nextjs project

Comment: Rewrites do not redirect the page. However, if you actually only want to embed the external page and still show additional content on your page an iframe is the only option.